# DataBricks ADLS Gen 2 Mount missing all subfolders and files

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

Finally getting to grips with Databricks.
I've mounted an ADLSGen2 account within databricks, however when I list my files I only have one folder within the mount. Can someone assist in where I am going wrong.

cmd1

```
adlsAccountName = "accountname"  
adlsContainerName = "databricks"
adlsFolderName = "ARCHIVE"
mountpoint = "/mnt/files"

applicationID = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "Secret02", key="AppID")

authenticationKey = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "Secret02", key="ClientSecret")

tenantID =  dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "Secret02", key="tenantid")

endpoint = "https://login.microsoft.com/" + tenantID + "/oauth2/token"
source = "abfss://" +adlsContainerName+"@"+adlsAccountName+".dfs.core.windows.net/"+adlsFolderName+"/"


configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
          "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
          "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": applicationID,
          "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": authenticationKey,
          "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": endpoint,
          "spark.databricks.sqldw.jdbc.service.principal.client.id": applicationID,
           "spark.databricks.sqldw.jdbc.service.principal.client.secret": authenticationKey
          }



dbutils.fs.mount(
source = source,
mount_point = mountpoint,
extra_configs = configs)
```

cmd2

```
%fs
ls "mnt/files"
```

[ADLS Gen2 Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KumGu.png)

[Databricks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcEp6.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have sub folder make sure to add subfolder at the end of blob storage URL and then mount.

As per your code follow below `source` syntax

```
source = "abfss://" +adlsContainerName+"@"+adlsAccountName+".dfs.core.windows.net/"+adlsFolderName+"/"+subfolderName+"/"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately because the subfolders are many your resolution would not fit. My partition looks like this ARCHIVE/[YEAR]/[Month]/[Day]/[Time]/[approx 150 files].parquet

Comment: hi , you need list of subfolder or list of files ?

Comment: like this 150 subfolders `ARCHIVE/[YEAR]/[Month]/[Day]/[Time]/` correct me if I am wrong